# Why chinese character can't be displayed after installing noto cjk?

Tags: fonts

I have donloaded noto cjk font package ,and installed it this way:

```
cd ~/Downloads    
unzip .zip
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto
sudo cp *otf *otc /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto
sudo fc-cache -f -v 
reboot
```

Why  chinese character can't be displayed  after installing  noto cjk?
Which job should i do to make os call noto cjk?
which configuration file should be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the config file for Chinese, here is the /etc/fonts/local.conf:

```
<fontconfig>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family">
      <string>serif</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Sans CJK TC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK SC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK JP Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK KR Regular</string>
    </edit>
  </match> 
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family">
      <string>sans-serif</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Sans CJK TC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK SC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK JP Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK KR Regular</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family">
      <string>monospace</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Sans CJK TC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK SC Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK JP Regular</string>
      <string>Noto Sans CJK KR Regular</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match>
        <test name="family" compare="contains">
                <string>Noto Sans CJK</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
                <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
                <const>hintfull</const>
        </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

1. change the permission of these fonts.

   `sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/*`
2. create a local.conf in /etc/fonts/ and paste the content which is listed above.

   `sudo vi /etc/fonts/local.conf`

Then it will call the Noto Sans CJK for Chinese.

By the way, Ubuntu 16.04LTS will set the Noto Sans CJK as default fonts for Traditional Chinese, Simplified Chinese, Japanese and Korean.