# Why chinese characters can be displayed in LXTerminal not in Root Terminal?

Tags: display, chinese, lxterminal

The desktop in my pc is lxde.I found that chinese character can be displayed in LXTerminal when to login with common user and chinese character can not be displayed in  Root Terminal when to login with root.
Why ? How to make chinese characters displayed in Root Terminal ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
find /  -name  '*fonts'
/usr/local/share/fonts
/usr/share/consolefonts
/usr/share/texmf/fonts
/usr/share/fonts
/etc/X11/fonts
/etc/fonts
/var/cache/fonts
/var/lib/xfonts
```

Which one of so many fonts in the result will i check with?
[image]

How to call noto cjk fonts to display chinese with the help of JulianLai  this way .

[call noto cjk fonts to display chinese](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751709/why-chinese-character-cant-be-displayed-after-installing-noto-cjk)

```
Locale:

1.  All locale:

        C
        C.UTF-8
        en_US.utf8
        POSIX
        zh_CN
        zh_CN.gb18030
        zh_CN.gb2312
        zh_CN.utf8

2.  Current locale:

        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        LANGUAGE=
        LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_ALL=

cat /etc/inputrc
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
```

It take no effect.

Comment: is the output of "locale" in those two windows different? Also, are both of thse terminals LXT?

Comment: What font is being used? Maybe the font's is only 'installed' in the `~/.fonts` directory and hence the root terminal can't find it.

Comment: Since your initial post, you have changed from DISPLAYING things to INPUTING them. :) Have a look at your ~/.inputrc for thoes two users. If I recall correctly you need "set input-meta on" and "set output-meta on"

Comment: It take no effect.